# Motion of a planet around a spherically distributed mass

Tags: general-relativity

I was studying a book which claims that, after a lot of math, the metric of the isotropic spacetime around a spherically symmetric is, approximately  $$ds^2 = -A(r)dt^2 + B(r)dt^2 + r^2 d\Omega^2$$

So, the motion of a planet around this mass is given by the Lagrangian L

$$L = [A(r)dt^2/d\tau^2 - B(r)dt^2/d\tau^2 - r^2 d\Omega^2/d\tau^2]^{1/2}$$

I am not sure how does we get this Lagrangian, probably i am forget something. Could you help me? I will not post any attempt to find it because, actually, i think this is derived by some definition of Lagrangian in spacetime that i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lagrangian of a single particle in General Relativity (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Lagrangian_mechanics#Lagrangian_formulation_in_general_relativity), for example) is given by:

$$\mathcal{L} = -mc^2\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu} \dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu} + \mathcal{L}_I,$$ where $\mathcal{L}_I$ represents an interaction of some sort (not gravity). In this case, the particle is essentially "free" (i.e., in free fall in a gravitational field) and so $\mathcal{L}_I = 0$. The form that you have therefore follows.